# How to use Import to extract data from website?

Tags: import, web-access, chemistry, webservices

I would like to extract data of surface properties and grain boundary properties for Cu polymorph #0 from the website: http://crystalium.materialsvirtuallab.org using Mathematica.

So far I tried with `Import`, but it doesn't seem to work because it seems to import data only from the main page, and not for the particular properties from element Cu:

```
Import["http://crystalium.materialsvirtuallab.org", "Data"]
(*
{" home ", {{{{" Cycle through different views > ", {{"Surface \
properties", {"Miller indices", "Area fraction"}, {"J/m 2", "eV/Å 2", 
        "eV"}}, {"{[{ surface.is_reconstructed ? '*' : ''}]}", 
       "{[{surface.surface_energy | number : 2}]}", 
       "{[{surface.surface_energy_EV_PER_ANG2 | number : 3}]}", 
       "{[{surface.work_function | number : 3}]}", 
       "{[{surface.area_fraction | number : 2 }]}", 
       "cif"}}}, {"Weighted surf. energy", "=", 
     "{[{ wulff.weighted_surface_energy |number : 2 }]} J/m 2 ( \
{[{wulff.weighted_surface_energy_EV_PER_ANG2 | number : 3 }]} eV/Å 2 \
)"}, {"Weighted work function", "=", 
     "{[{ wulff.weighted_work_function |number : 2 }]} eV"}, {"Shape \
factor", "=", 
     "{[{ wulff.shape_factor | number : 2 }]}"}, {"Surf. energy \
anisotropy", "=", 
     "{[{ wulff.surface_anisotropy | number : 3 }]}"}}, {{"Grain \
boundary properties", {"Type", "Rotation axis", "Rotation angle", 
      "GB plane"}, {"J/m 2", "eV/Å 2", "J/m 2", 
      "eV/Å 2"}}, {"{[{grain_boundary.sigma}]}", 
     "{[{grain_boundary.type}]}", 
     "{[{grain_boundary.rotation_angle | number : 2}]}", 
     "{[{grain_boundary.gb_energy | number : 2}]}", 
     "{[{grain_boundary.gb_energy_EV_PER_ANG2 | number : 3}]}", 
     "{[{grain_boundary.w_sep | number : 3}]}", 
     "{[{grain_boundary.w_sep_EV_PER_ANG2 | number : 2}]}", 
     "cif"}}}, {{"H", "He"}, {"Li ", "Be ", "B ", "C ", "N", "O", "F",
     "Ne"}, {"Na ", "Mg ", "Al ", "Si ", "P ", "S ", "Cl", 
    "Ar"}, {"K ", "Ca ", "Sc ", "Ti ", "V ", "Cr ", "Mn ", "Fe ", 
    "Co ", "Ni ", "Cu ", "Zn ", "Ga ", "Ge ", "As ", "Se ", "Br", 
    "Kr"}, {"Rb ", "Sr ", "Y ", "Zr ", "Nb ", "Mo ", "Tc ", "Ru ", 
    "Rh ", "Pd ", "Ag ", "Cd ", "In ", "Sn ", "Sb ", "Te ", "I", 
    "Xe"}, {"Cs ", "Ba ", "Hf ", "Ta ", "W ", "Re ", "Os ", "Ir ", 
    "Pt ", "Au ", "Hg ", "Tl ", "Pb ", "Bi ", "Po", "At", 
    "Rn"}, {"Fr", "Ra"}, {"La ", "Ce ", "Pr ", "Nd ", "Pm ", "Sm ", 
    "Eu ", "Gd ", "Tb ", "Dy ", "Ho ", "Er ", "Tm ", "Yb ", 
    "Lu "}, {"Ac ", "Th ", "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", 
    "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "Lr"}}}}
*)
```

Is it possible to import with Mathematica the tables with data that you can see in the website upon clicking on each chemical element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This url contains raw data:

```
Import["http://crystalium.materialsvirtuallab.org/crystallium/data/Cu"]
```

To access the html of the new page, here is a variation of the method provided in a previous answer, targeting polymorph #0 info. Note that I have added a pause to allow time for the script associated with the click to execute (otherwise I get the original html).

```
session = StartWebSession[]
WebExecute[session, 
 "OpenPage" -> "http://crystalium.materialsvirtuallab.org/"]

cu = WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> "#Cu"]
WebExecute[session, "ClickElement" -> cu]
Pause[2];
html = WebExecute[session, 
  "JavascriptExecute" -> 
   "return document.getElementsByClassName('polymorph')[0].outerHTML;"]

DeleteObject[session]
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this url works!

Comment: that's sufficient. I accept the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Using V12 or later

```
session = StartWebSession[]
WebExecute[session, "OpenPage" -> "http://crystalium.materialsvirtuallab.org/"]

cu = WebExecute[session, "LocateElements" -> "CSSSelector" -> "#Cu"]
WebExecute[session, "ClickElement" -> cu]

html = WebExecute[session, 
   "JavascriptExecute" -> "return document.documentElement.outerHTML;"];
ImportString[html, "Data"]

DeleteObject[session]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to get to website and pick the element, but ImportString appears to not return the result I want. I tried to use Import instead of ImportString in V12.1.1.0, but still no luck in importing.

Comment: @Ferca The code of this answer worked for me.

Comment: @AntonAntonov do you get the same output as when using the code from the other answer: ```Import["http://crystalium.materialsvirtuallab.org/crystallium/data/Cu"]``` ? This is is the output I am looking for. Perhaps I was not clear in my question.

Comment: @Ferca No, not the same answer. I was just saying the posted code worked.